# json.net Converting XML to JSON, how do I read / validate attributes

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

Given an xml containing:

```
<detailedreport analysis_size_bytes="220358752" engine_version="127144">
  <modules>
     <module name="Base.dll" compiler="MSIL_MSVC14_X86" os="Win32" architecture="CIL32" loc="764981" score="56" numflawssev0="6" numflawssev1="0" numflawssev2="6" numflawssev3="264" numflawssev4="4" numflawssev5="2"/>
     <module name="EpisodeDefinition.dll" compiler="MSIL_MSVC14_X86" os="Win32" architecture="CIL32" loc="1165845" score="66" numflawssev0="1" numflawssev1="0" numflawssev2="56" numflawssev3="149" numflawssev4="1" numflawssev5="0"/>
     <module name="UI.dll" compiler="MSIL_MSVC14_X86" os="Win32" architecture="CIL32" loc="1165845" score="79" numflawssev0="0" numflawssev1="0" numflawssev2="10" numflawssev3="73" numflawssev4="0" numflawssev5="0"/>
  </modules>
</detailedreport>
```

using Json.Net to process it:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(@"myxmlfile.xml");
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(xmlDoc);
var jobj = JObject.Parse(json);
var modules = jobj.SelectTokens("$..modules.module");
```

I'm only getting one "module", when I'm expecting 3, and I can't figure out how to get the information from the attributes? Specifically, I would like to be able to get a list of the module names.

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want to read an xml as JSON whereas you can serialise the XML doc into an object and then access the properties through the object?

Comment: While XML is fine, my shop relies more on C# and javascript. Sharing things with other team members, XML is way out of scope for them.

Answer (score 0):

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(@"myxmlfile.xml");

var rows = from row in xmlDoc.XPathSelectElements("//node()[local-name(.) = 'module']") select row;
var modules = rows.SelectMany(row => row.Attributes().Where(a => a.Name == "name").Select(a => a.Value));

modules.Dump();
```